# sticky left column in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, navigation, datatables

Is it possible to accomplish the following in jquery mobile?

I've got a grid

> ```
> <div class="ui-grid-a" >
>           <div  class="ui-block-a" >
>                  navigationtree
>           </div>
>
>           <div class="ui-block-b">
>                 datatable with 50+ rows
>           </div>
>  </div>
> ```

when the table has too much data a scrollbar should appear and
block-b should be scrollable where block-a should be sticky at all times
so that the navigation stays in place.

is it possible to accomplish such a behaviour in jquery mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because 2 grid blocks share a width of 50% each its easy to achieve by setting block a to a fixed position and block b to float right.

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/59v0gy6w/

```
<div  class="ui-block-a" style="position:fixed">

<div class="ui-block-b" style="float:right">
```

Answer (score 1):

cytasos has given a good answer! if you actually want just the ui-block-b to be scrollable, you can do it this way:

First scale the ui-content div to fill the device/screen height:

```
function ScaleContentToDevice() {
    scroll(0, 0);
    var content = $.mobile.getScreenHeight() - $(".ui-header").outerHeight() - $(".ui-footer").outerHeight() - $(".ui-content").outerHeight() + $(".ui-content").height();
    $(".ui-content").height(content);
}

$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function () {
    ScaleContentToDevice();
});

$(window).on("resize orientationchange", function () {
    ScaleContentToDevice();
});
```

Next set the grid height to 100% and the block-b div to 100% height and overflow in CSS:

```
.ui-grid-a {
    height: 100%;
}
.ui-block-b {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/4uvLcog5/3/)**

Comment: @cytasos, thanks, I liked your solution because it is simpler and I would never have thought of it :)

Comment: thx a lot this is really another cool way!!! the thing is that the navigation is a tree which could be larger than the screen which means it should be scrollable too!

Comment: @AndreasZeiner, no problem just make the left block scrollable too: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/4uvLcog5/4/